# Vue 3: Remove objects (Proxies) from Array

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, vue-reactivity

I have a vue3 project and I use the composition API.
I have a component which shows some items (called tokens in this case).

```
<script setup>
import { ref, onMounted, toRaw } from 'vue'
import RotaryToken from './RotaryToken.vue'

const tokens = ref([])

const addToken = () => {
  const id = new Date().valueOf()
  tokens.value.push({ id })
}

const removeToken = (id) => {
  console.log('id: ', id)
  tokens.value = tokens.value.filter((token) => {
    console.log('toRaw(token): ', toRaw(token))
    return token.id !== id
  })
  console.log('tokens.value: ', tokens.value)
}
</script>

<template>
  <div class="canvas">
    <div class="controls"><button @click="addToken">Add token</button></div>
    <div v-if="tokens.length <= 0" class="fallback-message">Place tokens here</div>
    <RotaryToken
      v-for="token in tokens"
      :key="token.id"
      @destroy="removeToken"
      :id="token.id"
    />
  </div>
</template>
```

The RotaryToken itself can emit a destroy event so I can remove itself from the array and therefore it should be removed. (I tried to self destroy a rotary token but no success).

Unfortunately I cannot remove a token from the reactive `tokens` array . The problem lies somewhere in Vues Reactivity stuff.

[image]

I can see that the id is the correct one but `tokens.value.filter` just does not work.
I tried with splicing instead of filtering, added `nextTick`. Nothing worked.

Maybe somebody has an idea how to remove a token from the array and make it therefore rerender the template and removing destroyed tokens?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. There's no such problem in general, it's specific to your case. Most times it doesn't make sense to put the emphasis on "proxy", it's just a way vue implements reactivity, and most times it's transparent to a user. There would be a problem if you compared by object reference and not id in filter, but this is not the case.

Comment: Have you tried to log your tokens value with ```console.log(tokens.value[0].id)``` ?

Comment: @EstusFlask you are right. I thought it was linked to reactivity and more of a general question. It was a stupid mistake though. I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your filter test.

```
tokens.value.filter((token) => {
    console.log('toRaw(token): ', toRaw(token))
    return token.id !== id
})
```

where you believe `id` is a number, but as your screenshot shows, it's an **object** called "id" but also with an `id` property.  So your filter test is only returning tokens where `token.id !== object`

Either pass the actual `id` property to the function, or access the property on the object which would be `id.id`:

```
tokens.value.filter((token) => {
    console.log('toRaw(token): ', toRaw(token))
    return token.id !== id.id
})
```